# Start tab for new thread, and close tab and end thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, tabs

I followed this tutorial on http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1867-create-tab-control-wpf.aspx to create closable tabs for a WPF application.

I'm creating a multithreaded application and I'll be using closable tabs from the link above.  I want each thread to have its own tab and update it as it runs. Should I create the tab inside the new thread or create the tab in the main thread and update it from the new thread? What is the proper way of doing this?

How can I make the thread end when the tab is closed?

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the UI thread to render/display tabs. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20140405073459/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)). As the title says "Build More Responsive Apps With The Dispatcher".

Answer (score 1):

Neither. Have the main thread create the tab, update the tabs when directed to do so by the various other threads, and command the thread to terminate when the tab is closed.

Learn how to [use the dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx#S3) to coordinate threads.

If a thread does some work that, by the program logic, should not be done at that time, that thread's code is broken. Fix it. If the thread is not supposed to continue running when the tab is closed, code it not to continue running when the tab is closed. Don't leave the thread broken, coded to do work when that work should not be done by program logic, and then try to fix it someplace else.

This is a backwards way of thinking about threads. Threads are just vehicles that do work. You control them by controlling the work. You write every line of code that the threads execute. If you don't want a thread to X in condition Y, code it not to do X in condition Y.

In sum, if program logic says work X should not be done when tab Y is closed, do this:

1) Somewhere, store a flag that indicates whether work X should be done or not.

2) In the code that does work X, check this flag. If it's set to *no*, don't do the work. By program logic, the work should not be done. Doing it is *broken*.

3) When the tab is closed, have the UI thread set the flag to stop doing work X.

Tabs should not correspond to threads. That makes no logical sense. Tabs should correspond to whatever is displayed in the tab. (They may 'happen to' correspond to threads indirectly, but this is not primary. Threads really correspond to whatever work is associated with the tab.)

In principle, if a different thread took over the same work, shouldn't it still be in the same tab? Or should the same data suddenly go in a different tab just because a different thread is producing it? That you happen to always do the work that goes in that tab in the same thread is an implementation detail that should *not* be reflected that way in the architecture. As you have learned, that just creates silliness where you have to figure out which thread is doing the work when you really don't care.

Comment: Here is where I'm stuck at: Lets say I create 7 threads which would open 7 tabs, when I close one of the tabs, it has to know which thread belongs to that tab so I can abort it. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: @Ayra You do not want to create one Tab per Thread because WPF does not allow threads to alter objects created on other threads. Instead you want to create a thread for the duration of some long running process, which automatically ends when the process is finished. You could also create a control that inherits from `TabItem`, which would start a thread in Constructor and ends the thread when the TabItem gets disposed. I wouldn't recommend that route though.

Comment: @Arya: It does not have to know which thread belongs to that tab, because it doesn't care which thread gets stopped. It's the thread's job to terminate when the job it is doing is done. The UI thread should simply indicate that the job associated with that tab is done, and the tab thread shouldn't continue running after its job is done. (You're coding everything, so make it work together.)

Comment: @David Schwartz The work of the thread will never end. This is a network application and I want it to run 24/7 and use the tabs to write the updates. When creating a ClosableTab is it possible to pass it the thread name and return the name through RoutedEventArgs?

Comment: @Arya: The work of the thread ends when the tab is closed. You don't want to do anything to the thread, you want to do something to the work the thread is doing, specifically, indicate that it's finished. Then any thread that tries to work on it would notice there's no more work to do and terminate itself (or do something else). You are thinking about this in a backwards way. Think about the work that no longer needs to be done. Threads are just vehicles to do work. The work dictates what the threads do. They do the work that needs to be done and stop when no more work needs to be done.

Comment: @David Schwartz I put Console.beep() in an endless loop of the method which gets started by the new thread and when I close the tab I can still hear the beeping. I have attached the full project here http://www.mediafire.com/?q0cd87rz8hg7bp7 since this is a network application, the work would never end, so I'm trying to find the correct way of aborting the thread when the tab is closed.

Comment: @Arya: You should not put 'Console.beep' in an endless loop. You don't want to beep forever. You want to beep until the tab is closed. Write the code to do what you actually want rather than making it do something else and then later having to 'force' it to do the right thing. It should not keep beeping after the tab is closed because when the tab is closed, its beeping is done. If it keeps beeping after the work is done, it's broken. **Fix it**.

Comment: The thread should not be coded to beep when it is not supposed to beep. It is not supposed to beep if the tab is closed. If it does, the thread's logic is broken. It calls 'beep' when it should not beep. Fix the thread. Do not call beep unless you want to beep. (You are thinking about this 100% backwards. Forget about what threads happen to do the work. Make the code that does the work do the work, and only the work, that is supposed to be done. When the tab is closed, you are not supposed to beep. So why are you?)